# Encrypted RSA key not working with MongoDB in Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to create X.509 authentication with MongoDB. It works fine in Linux, but MongoClient gives me problem in this step in Windows.

My client.pem look like this

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDOjCCAiICAQMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwYTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQVUxDDAKBgNV
..............
BgHF6LZFIyTXqiOnrHI=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,A48C7B02D7FD03093209F2473401A08B

/eZVAE8ycfqoDOgQuGDR/cumw/nJQpE2MLrh4G0JjohDIU98DiU+/fDJ/FnbfCzH
2Dn/wTJiTUyvaZL3PbvDL9TXKMGtxgUCOJyGQf18pJrO5dRVLEpmOlnyCrKHQ2RA
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am getting this error `Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration CryptDecodeObjectEx failed to get size of object: ASN1 bad tag value met.` with mongodb.exe when I try to use it.

Note: If I remove encryption from private key, it works fine. But I need it. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: A missing feature is a missing feature I suppose. You could manually remove the encryption in advance, but beware that any intermediate file is likely to be preserved in some way or another, even after wiping instead of deletion. Check if the latest version is installed, it may have more features; it is a bit weird for this to be available on one platform and not another.

Answer (score 0):

the same issue with mongodb 4.0.4
But the same configuration works with 3.6.9 just fine